# Limit problem (limit of a sum as a definite integral)

Tags: integration, limits

Could somebody please help me with this:

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{(1^2+1)}{(1-n^3)}+\frac{(2^2+2)}{(2-n^3)}....\frac{(n^2+n)}{(n-n^3)}$$

I have an intuition that it can be expressed as an integral and as the general method prescribes, I am trying to get $\frac rn$ term in it so that I can replace it with $x$ and $1/n$ with $dx$ but I am unable to do so. I tried by representing a general term as $$\frac{(r^2+r)}{(r-n^3)}$$ but taking out $n^3$ or $r^2$ or $r$ ain't working for me (unable to manipulate it further).

Thank you.

Comment: Try $$
\sum\limits_{r = 1}^n {\frac{{r^2  - r}}{{n^3 }}}  \le \sum\limits_{r = 1}^n {\frac{{r^2  - r}}{{n^3  - r}}}  \le \sum\limits_{r = 1}^n {\frac{{r^2 }}{{n^3  - n}}}  = \frac{{n^3 }}{{n^3  - n}}\sum\limits_{r = 1}^n {\frac{{r^2 }}{{n^3 }}} .
$$

Comment: @Gary Am really sorry, edited the question now, it was addition in the numerator and not subtraction

Comment: A similar trick will do.

Comment: @Gary I tried it but i am getting my result as 1/3 whereas it should be (-1/3)

Comment: Note that for convenience I am estimating the sum with $n^3-r$ instead of $r-n^3$. So the final result is $-1$ times of what comes out of this method.